# Getting error while using react native component on Android 4.4.2 and 4.2.2

Tags: android, react-native

While trying to init the react native component in Android app getting this error on **Android os** version **4.4.2** and **4.2.2**.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.VerifyError: com/facebook/soloader/g at
>   com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.initImpl$1a54e370(SoLoader.java:189) at
>   com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.init(SoLoader.java:1105) at
>   com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.initializeSoLoaderIfNecessary(ReactInstanceManager.java:1358)
>   at
>   com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:227)

Answer (score 3):

Fix for crash:

```
# SoLoader
-keep class com.facebook.soloader.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader {
     static <fields>;
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7530

Comment: I added to proguard-rules.pro but it steel has the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
Add implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' to dependencies in app/build.gradle

In MainApplication.java:
import androidx.multidex.MultiDex; // Note: You might need to replace this with: 

import android.support.multidex.Multidex;
import android.content.Context;

Add following to MainApplication.java:

  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
```